# Why does int exp1 = 14/20*100; equals '0' in java?

Tags: java, math, int

I'm trying to do some basic math and it keeps popping up as `0`. I'm sure it has to do with it being an `int` but I don't know how to work around it. I need to use integers but the math to arrive at those integers uses decimals. How do I do it?

Comment: Good lord, not again....integer division works this way in every language.

Comment: @duffymo not in weak-typed languages ;)

Comment: Really?  Post a JavaScript example.  I'm pretty sure that two integers will act this way when you divide them.

Comment: the problem is I didn't know what to search for to find out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not special to blackberry, it's standard java behaviour.

This is because you're doing integer math:

```
int subexpr1 = 14 / 20; // 0
int subexpr2 =  subexpr1 * 100; // 0
```

Use a double instead or change the order

```
int expr1 = (int) 14.0/20 * 100; // Very small possibility of rounding errors
int expr2 = 14 * 100 / 20; // Will ignore fraction parts
```

Answer (score 8):

That's integer division.

To get non-integer results, use `double`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to 14*100/20 - and then it will give what you want.

I.e. change the sequence of operations (14/20 is 0)

Answer (score -1):

Your result is being cast as an `int`, so you are losing precision.

Try

```
double exp1 = 14/20.0*100;
```

Comment: How do I then cast the double as an int and round it?

Comment: ie. 0.65 * 10 = 6.5 but cast as an int so it rounds to 7

Comment: @JoeyJohnJohn Use Math#round: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double). My original comment was because the original answer had `14/20`, not `14/20.0`