# Why is my int 0?

Tags: java, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does int exp1 = 14/20*100; equals ‘0’ in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335837/why-does-int-exp1-14-20100-equals-0-in-java)

I am using this:

`int newWidth = Math.round(297 * (40 / 414));`

In the code the numbers are actually variables, but those are what they were holding, and when I run the code `newWidth` comes back as 0, and I was expecting 28 or 29. I don't see what is wrong here...

Comment: 40 / 414 equals to 0

Comment: Search the web for "[integer arithmetic](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/11008.aspx)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`40 / 414` is rounded to `0` immediately as it only works with integers. You must either cast one of the operands to `double`/`float` or use `double` immediately:

```
int newWidth = (int)Math.round(297 * (40.0 / 414));
```

or:

```
int newWidth = (int)Math.round(297 * ((double)40 / 414));
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `40/414` equals to `0`, so `297*0 = 0` and `Math.round(0) = 0`

Use doubles instead.

Answer (score 3):

`int newWidth = (int)Math.round(297 * (40d / 414));`

Answer (score 2):

Change to `int newWidth = (int)Math.round(297 * (40.0 / 414));`

Answer (score 2):

An int in java uses no decimal places... Therefore you should use a double for this. It is giving you a 0 because inside the () 40/ 414 = 0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem starts with 40/414: that's integer division, which returns an int.  In this case: 0.

To fix it, cast one of those ints to a double or float, e.g. ((float) 40 / 414).

Answer (score 1):

The result of `40/414` is zero. This is a consequence of integer division. Change either numerator or denominator to a floating point value to get your desired result

Answer (score 1):

Gonna throw my 2 cents in... as noted, the issue lies in the integer division. Another method for forcing this division to treat the result as a double:

```
int newWidth = Math.round(297 * (40.0 / 414));
```

Answer (score 0):

40/414 is rounded to 0.

What you probably want is

```
int newWidth = (297 * 40) / 414;
```